# Vue-resource and http-proxy-middleware not routing to backend

Tags: proxy, vue.js, vue-resource, http-proxy-middleware

I am new to Vue js and writing a front end for a simple task tracker app. I am trying to use vue-resource and http-proxy-middleware to have the app connect to my backend. Backend is on port 3000, and the Vue js front end is on port 8080.

I used the proxy set up described on the [Vue docs](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html).

**The method:**

```
saveTask() {
    this.$http.get('/api', {title: this.taskTitle})
      .then(response => {
        console.log("success");
      }, response => {
        console.log("error");
      });
  }
```

**My Proxy Table:** (in config.index.js under dev)

```
 proxyTable: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': ''
    }
  }
},
```

When I start up the server I see:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://localhost:3000
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
> Starting dev server...
```

On the request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api 404 (Not Found)
```

So it looks like the proxy is not working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup looks good and the requests should look like they're coming from `8080` since it is a proxy.

Are you sure something should be returning where you're looking? I have literally the same setup and it works.

My guess is since http://localhost:8080/api can't be found either can http://localhost:3000 since they're the same thing.

If that doesn't solve your problem you can dig a little deeper and debug and see if anything looks funny there.

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': '',
    },
  },
},
```

Here goes a shot of everything working with my stuff:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into it and make sure something is listening on 3000

Comment: You were spot on! The route on the backend wasn't listening for the exact route.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was setting up a **vue.config.js** file on the root dir of the vue project (that is at the same level that pacakge.json) and within that file I used this code:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now that the proxy was setup in the vue app the request would reach my express server :D